# cgi/fastcgi process - 0% CPU and N% Memory?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, fastcgi

I have php wordpress website hosted on IIS, have been using FastCGI, below is my fastCGI configuration

[image]

Below is screenshot of task manager
[image]

There are many fastCGI processes that are using 0% CPU but consuming certain portion of RAM, is this ok ? or there is any misconfiguration due to which this is happening

I did research online to find reason for same, but did not found anything.

Comment: I don't know the details about this, but even so - they are using only about 15MB per process.  This is minimal and would be their idle state.  Are you having any issues with the server or errors from the application?

Comment: @NigelRen, My website is loading slow that's only observation , No error found in event logs

Comment: FastCGI on IIS allows reuse of an existing pool of non-exiting processes. If there is a new request, IIS does not start a new process, but lets the previously idle process handle it. You can try [process recycling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-php-applications-on-iis/configure-php-process-recycling-behavior) in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

As most web servers do, IIS [uses its php processes multiple times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis#best-practices-for-configuring-fastcgi-and-php) before restarting them. It leaves idle processes running so it can serve incoming requests with out the extra latency delay of spinning up new processes.

Comment: But this is more like a thing from FastCGI specification than any web server, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI "Instead of creating a new process for each request, FastCGI uses persistent processes to handle a series of requests. These processes are owned by the FastCGI server, not the web server.[1]"